# How to switch on a 4-character string in C?

Tags: c, string, macros, switch-statement

I need to switch based on a 4-character string. I put the string in a union so I can at least refer to it as a 32-bit integer.

```
union
{
    int32u  integer;
    char    string[4];
}software_version;
```

But now I don't know what to write in the case statements.  I need some kind of macro to convert a 4-character string literal into the integer. E.G.

```
#define STRING_TO_INTEGER(s)    ?? What goes here ??
#define VERSION_2_3_7           STRING_TO_INTEGER("0237")
#define VERSION_2_4_1           STRING_TO_INTEGER("0241")

switch (array[i].software_version.integer)
{
    case VERSION_2_3_7:
        break;

    case VERSION_2_4_1:
        break;
}
```

Is there a way to make the STRING_TO_INTEGER() macro. Or is there a better way to handle the switch?

Comment: Are you aware that this is not portable across endianness boundaries? It might be a better idea to simply define a version integer that's incremented or computed from the numerical version at program start.

Comment: I don't think you can go from string -> number at compile time.

Comment: Why do you insist on converting your `VERSION` constants from strings with a macro? You could simply... you know... put integers directly (e.g. `#define VERSION_2_3_7 237`)...

Comment: @SethCarnegie One can use `sscanf` to parse integers within strings.

Comment: Also note that if you stick with a character array representation of version and you want 4 characters, you should define the string element of the struct to take 5 characters, one for the NULL.

Comment: @thiton Yes I am aware of that, but the endianness will not be a problem for reasons that are too long to fit into a comment.

Comment: @Romain Because 237 is not the same as "0237". The Correct value is 0x30323337.

Comment: @Lou There is no NULL. This is not a NULL terminated string. It is a fixed length string.

Comment: @Romain You cannot use sscanf to define the labels in a case statement. Please try to understand the question properly.

Comment: @Romain I did say "compile time" and `sscanf` is a function, so my statement still stands.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I missed the "compile time" part of it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

```
#define VERSION_2_3_7 '0237'
```

Comment: He needs to go from string to number, not number to string.

Comment: The question is about the opposite direction.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, see upper comment

Comment: I am sorry. I misunderstood your answer. I was unaware of this syntax in C. I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: People, stop down-voting this. It's actually the correct answer.

Comment: the code id non-portable, though: the interpretation of multi-character integer character constants is implementation-defined and probably varies with endianness

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, this answer is flawed, don't use it like that. Character constants that contain more than one char like the proposed `'0237'` are compiler specific. And in addition there is no reason for you to use such a cruft if you are really satisfied by just individual defines. Just define it as a long unsigned decimal number, e.g `237UL`.

Comment: @Jen No. 237UL is the wrong number. 0x30323337 is the right number. neagoegab's solution produces the correct code, and the portability can be checked with an assert in the code.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, the convention you choose going from string to integer is completely up to you as long as you are consistent with yourself. But we should stop this, you want this here, this is your code, do as you please.

Comment: @Jens the point is to reinterpret the 4x8bits of the string as a 32-bit integer. Not to parse the string. Any string, including "0_?Q" can be re-intrepreted as an integer. However, only numberic strings can be parsed into an integer.

Answer (score 7):

Portable example code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHARS_TO_U32(c1, c2, c3, c4) (((uint32_t)(uint8_t)(c1) | \
    (uint32_t)(uint8_t)(c2) << 8 | (uint32_t)(uint8_t)(c3) << 16 | \
    (uint32_t)(uint8_t)(c4) << 24))

static inline uint32_t string_to_u32(const char *string)
{
    assert(strlen(string) >= 4);
    return CHARS_TO_U32(string[0], string[1], string[2], string[3]);
}

#define VERSION_2_3_7 CHARS_TO_U32('0', '2', '3', '7')
#define VERSION_2_4_1 CHARS_TO_U32('0', '2', '4', '1')

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert(argc == 2);
    switch(string_to_u32(argv[1]))
    {
        case VERSION_2_3_7:
        case VERSION_2_4_1:
        puts("supported version");
        return 0;

        default:
        puts("unsupported version");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The code only assumes the existence of the integer types `uint8_t` and `uint32_t` and is agnostic to width and signedness of type `char` as well as endianness. It is free of collisions as long as the character encoding only uses values in range of `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 2):

You switch on four-character-codes like this

```
switch (fourcc) {
case 'FROB':
}
```

Note the difference: `"XXXX"` is a string, `'XXXX'` is a character/integer literal.

However, I would propose you use seperate version numbers instead, e.g.:

```
struct Version {
    int major, minor, patch;
};

bool smaller (Version lhs, Version rhs) {
    if (lhs.major < rhs.major) return true;
    if (lhs.major > rhs.major) return false;
    if (lhs.minor < rhs.minor) return true;
    if (lhs.minor > rhs.minor) return false;
    if (lhs.patch < rhs.patch) return true;
    if (lhs.patch > rhs.patch) return false; // redundant, for readabiltiy

    return false; // equal
}
```

Comment: you are misintrepreting the standard. Accessing another member than the one to which was last written is only UB if the value happens to be a trap representation for the other type. `int32u` (I suppose this is the same as `uint32_t`) has no trap representations.

Comment: I don't understand how this helps my switch statement.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: You can only switch on integer types, switching on strings/char arrays is not defined.

Comment: @Jens: I'll remove that phrase. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @phresnel Yes, I know that, as is obvious from my question. That's why I want an automagical way to convert the string into an integer.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: Then the title of your question is wrong. It should be "How to convert X to Y".

Comment: @phresnel: I considered that, but I thought this title would be better because the switch is the fundamental problem I am trying to solve, there might actually be a better way to approach it.

Answer (score -2):

```
int versionstring_to_int(char * str)
{
char temp [ 1+ sizeof software_version.string ]; /* typically 1+4 */

if (!str || ! *str) return -1;
memcpy (temp, str, sizeof temp -1);
temp [sizeof temp -1] = 0;

return atoi (temp );
}
```

EDIT:

```
#define STRING_TO_INTEGER(s)    versionstring_to_int(s)
#define VERSION_2_3_7           237
#define VERSION_2_4_1           241

switch ( STRING_TO_INTEGER( array[i].software_version.string) )
{
case VERSION_2_3_7:
    break;

case VERSION_2_4_1:
    break;
}
```

Comment: No, this does not work because this cannot be used as in a case statement.

Comment: Yes it can, just use the numeric IDs in the cases. They are supposed to be literals, and carefully matched by _the programmer_ to the corresponding code block. Why would one want a string as a case label when a number is just as readable, and less error-prone?

Comment: What if the string contained letters? E.G. "ABC1" -> 0x41424331

Comment: Well, you'd have to parse it, wouldn't you? And it does not seem to make much sense to change the naming/numbering scheme in the midlife-crisis of a project. Schemes like these are supposed to be stable.

Comment: I think that most people have missed (or don't understand) the concept of re-interpreting the bits of a string as an integer.

Comment: the point is to reinterpret the 4x8bits of the string as a 32-bit integer. Not to parse the string. Any 4-character string, including "0_?Q" can be re-intrepreted as an integer. However, only numberic strings can be parsed into an integer.